# MobaXterm Busybox strange setup

Tags: mobaxterm

I am using MobaXterm portable.
I found a strange setup, summarized here.

External commands in `/bin` work fine. E.g., with `/bin/ssh.exe` I can `ssh` ok.

Internal commands are

1. "redirected" to busybox, as

   ```
   $ which cat
   /bin/cat
   $ ll /bin/cat
   lrwxrwxrwx    1 USER001  UsersGrp        16 Jul 24 07:42 /bin/cat -> /bin/busybox.exe
   ```
2. at the same time aliased to files that apparently do not exist.

   ```
   $ type cat
   cat is aliased to `/bin/cat.exe'
   ```

These aliases apparently take precedence over files in PATH, so the commands do not work.

```
$ cat myfile
bash: /bin/cat.exe: No such file or directory
```

If I unalias, `cat` does not look for `/bin/cat.exe` but for `/bin/busybox.exe`, and everything is "back to normal".

```
$ unalias cat
$ cat myfile
Hello world
...
```

**How can I get normal behaviour (either without aliases or with the presence of the alias targets)?**
I mean not to write my own unaliases in `.bashrc`, this shouldn´t be needed.
Moreover, perhaps I would be breaking something.

**Why would MobaXterm setup things like this?**

PS: In the initial state, even `ls` does not work, for the same reason.
But `ll` works, since

```
$ type ll
ll is aliased to `_bbf ls -l'
$ type _bbf
_bbf is a function
...
```

Answer (score 1):

**How can I get normal behaviour?**

Workarounds:

1. `unalias`ing by hand, so `/bin/busybox.exe` is actually used.

   Below I add a script for that.
2. Copying `.exe` files from the temporary `root` dir when it is available, so the external versions are used.

**Why would MobaXterm setup things like this?**

When not using a *Persistent root (/) directory*, this is obtained

```
$ which cat
/bin/cat
$ ll /bin/cat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 RY16205 UsersGrp 49703 jul. 28 07:12 /bin/cat
$ type cat
cat is aliased to `/bin/cat.exe'
$ ll /bin/cat.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 USER001 UsersGrp 49703 jul. 28 07:12 /bin/cat.exe
$ cat myfile
Hello world
...
$ unalias cat
$ type cat
cat is hashed (/bin/cat)
$ cat myfile
Hello world
...
```

So any of the two `cat`s work (internal `busybox` and external versions; I do not know if they are exactly the same).
This is because `/bin` points to `C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Temp\Mxt108\bin` and `cat.exe` is there.

But when using a Persistent root (/) directory, `/bin` points to `<Persistent root (/) directory\bin`, and `cat.exe` is not created there.
The former temporary `root` dir is removed as soon as MXT is closed.
**So this is probably a configuration error from MobaXterm.**
If so, the only option seems a workaround, as above.

---

Script for unaliasing:

```
#!/bin/bash

export ROOTDIR_WIN=$(cygpath -wl /)
if [[ ${ROOTDIR_WIN##*\\} == "Mxt108" ]] ; then
    # Not using a Persistent root dir. Do not need to unalias. 
    echo "Not using a Persistent root dir. Do not need to unalias."
else
    # Using a Persistent root dir. Need to unalias.
    exe_linux_list="bash busybox chmod cygstart cygtermd cygwin-console-helper dircolors dwm_w32 echo grep ls MoTTY ssh ssh-pageant test twm_w32 wc xkbcomp_w32 XWin_MobaX"

    for exe_linux in ${exe_linux_list} ; do
        if [[ $(type -t ${exe_linux}) == "alias" ]] ; then
            #type ${exe_linux}
            unalias ${exe_linux}
        fi
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

On my MobaXterm system, /etc/profile sources /etc/baseprofile which includes aliases for all of these sorts of things, i.e.

```
alias "cat"="_bbf cat"
```

and checking that from my command prompt yields what I would expect:

```
$ type cat
cat is aliased to `_bbf cat'
```

Have you changed your system somehow so that /etc/baseprofile is not being sourced? Or have you changed /etc/baseprofile?

It also appears that you've installed the regular GNU Coreutils package, as I don't have a /bin/cat.exe.

```
$ ll /bin/cat.exe
ls: /bin/cat.exe: No such file or directory
```

Perhaps that's where your problem started but the _bbf function is supposed to handle that. Which again leads me to the belief that you've changed /etc/baseprofile somehow.

Answer (score 0):

At most time, it is cool. This error maybe caused by wrong path match of `cat.exe`.

As for me, when I run `git log`, the same error message comes out. It is due to `PATH` variable. There are two `dirs` and both of them contain `git.exe`. One of them is half-done with a small size. And `Mobaxterm` choose it. :D

I confirm this by run `which git` and it will give the actual path out.

I fix it by

```
alias git='/drives/C/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git.exe'
```

The following is my `dirs`.

```
├─cmd
│      git-gui.exe
│      git-lfs.exe
│      git.exe                              # oops
│      gitk.exe
│      start-ssh-agent.cmd
│      start-ssh-pageant.cmd
├─mingw64
│  ├─bin
│  │      git-upload-pack.exe
│  │      git.exe                           # the right one
```